# Correct way of using classes with Python asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

What is the correct method of dealing with a blocking class, when using Python asyncio?

For example:

```
import asyncio
import time

class getImage(object):
    def __init__(self,):
        time.sleep(0.5)
        self.image_sim = "image"


async def main():
    print('starting main loop')
    func1 = asyncio.create_task(my_func1())
    print("Waiting for func1 to complete") 
    await func1
    print('finished main loop')

async def my_func1():
    print("starting func1")
    image = getImage()
    print(image.image_sim)
    print('done func 1')

asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

Is this proper, or is there a more 'asyncio' way of doing this?

I tried to add `async` to the `init` function, and then `await` for it later on:

```
class getImage(object):
    async def __init__(self,):
        time.sleep(0.05)
        self.image_sim = "image"


async def main():
    print('starting main loop')
    func1 = asyncio.create_task(my_func1())
    print("Waiting for func1 to complete") 
    await func1
    print('finished main loop')

async def my_func1():
    print("starting func1")
    image = getImage()
    await image
    print(image.image_sim)
    print('done func 1')


asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

Comment: Replace `image = getImage()` with `image = await asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor(None, getImage)`. The accepted answer won't help you if your class is inherently _blocking_, as I understand to be the case from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `async` `classmethod` in `getImage`. The `classmethod` can perform the 0.5 second delay required before the `image_sim` attribute is set:

```
import asyncio
class getImage(object):
   def __init__(self, img):
      self.image_sim = img
   @classmethod
   async def get_image(cls):
      await asyncio.sleep(0.5) #sleep for 0.5 seconds
      return cls('image') #return instance of getImage with image_sim set to "image"

async def main():
   print('starting main loop')
   func1 = asyncio.create_task(my_func1())
   print("Waiting for func1 to complete") 
   await func1
   print('finished main loop')

async def my_func1():
   print("starting func1")
   image = await getImage.get_image() #await the async classmethod of getImage(object)
   print(image.image_sim)
   print('done func 1')

asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes sense - glad you posted before the 'power tripper' closed it

Comment: @MattG Glad to help!